# How do I make the program roll the previous number of dice by just clicking enter?

Tags: python-3.x

This is what I have so far. It works great if you want to roll different amounts of dice each time, but if you are playing a game like Sequence Dice its can get pretty frustrating and monotonous. I want it to be able to roll the previous number of dice rolled when you click enter without having to enter a new value.

````
from random import randint

run = False
dice_num = 0
roll_num = 0
total_sum = 0

print()
print("Welcome to dice roller!")
print()
print("To quit, just type stop at any time.")

while run == False:
    print()
    num_of = input("How many dice do you want to roll? ")
    print()

    if num_of.lower() == "stop":
        print()
        print("Thank you!")
        print(f"You rolled a total of {dice_num} dice in {roll_num} rolls.")
        print()
        break

    try:
        act_num = int(num_of)
        print("You rolled...")
        roll_num += 1
        while act_num > 0:
            dice_out = randint(1, 6)
            print(dice_out)
            act_num -= 1
            dice_num += 1
            total_sum += dice_out
        print()
        print(f"Sum: {total_sum}")
        total_sum = 0
    except ValueError:
        print("Try Again.")


run == False```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the job. I created variable `previous_dice_num` At the end of each loop, the value of `num_of` will be stored in `previous_dice_num`. Then, whenever the user enters nothing, the value of `previous_dice_num` will be used as `num_of`.

```py
from random import randint

run = False
dice_num = 0
roll_num = 0
total_sum = 0
previous_dice_num = 0

print()
print("Welcome to dice roller!")
print()
print("To quit, just type stop at any time.")

while run == False:
    print()
    num_of = input("How many dice do you want to roll? ")
    print()
    if num_of == '':
        num_of = previous_dice_num


    if num_of.lower() == "stop":
        print()
        print("Thank you!")
        print(f"You rolled a total of {dice_num} dice in {roll_num} rolls.")
        print()
        break

    try:
        act_num = int(num_of)
        print("You rolled...")
        roll_num += 1
        while act_num > 0:
            dice_out = randint(1, 6)
            print(dice_out)
            act_num -= 1
            dice_num += 1
            total_sum += dice_out
        print()
        print(f"Sum: {total_sum}")
        total_sum = 0
    except ValueError:
        print("Try Again.")

    previous_dice_num = num_of
```